# Android studio, не получается добавить запись в БД

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Пытаюсь произвести добавление записи в БД, но выходит ошибка. Наверняка здесь упущена какая-то мелочь, но я не понимаю какая, прошу помощи.

Код ошибки из "Run" (строка 65 в "Registration" - это последняя строка в коде для вставки записи в БД):

```
 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting email=admin@mail.ru money=0 password=12345 record=0 login=admin
                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email (code 2067)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:789)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1501)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1371)
                          at dc.galos.View.Registration$1.onClick(Registration.java:65)
                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5280)
                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21768)
                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5917)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Сам код для вставки записи в SQLite:

```
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
databaseHelper.create_db();

db = databaseHelper.open();

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_LOGIN,loginEditText.getText().toString());
contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PASSWORD,passwordEditText.getText().toString());
contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_EMAIL,emailEditText.getText().toString());
contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_MONEY, 0);
contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RECORD, 0);

db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null, contentValues);
```

Код DatabaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH; // полный путь к базе данных
    private static String DB_NAME = "galos.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
    public static final String TABLE = "users"; // название таблицы в бд
    // названия столбцов
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_LOGIN = "login";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String COLUMN_MONEY = "money";
    public static final String COLUMN_RECORD = "record";
    private static Toast toast;
    private Context myContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
        this.myContext=context;
        DB_PATH =context.getFilesDir().getPath() + DB_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {
    }

    public void create_db(){
        InputStream myInput = null;
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(DB_PATH);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                //получаем локальную бд как поток
                myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // Путь к новой бд
                String outFileName = DB_PATH;

                // Открываем пустую бд
                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                // побайтово копируем данные
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            Log.d("DatabaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public SQLiteDatabase open()throws SQLException {

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public static void showInformation(Context context, String text) {
        if (toast != null) {
            toast.cancel();
        }
        toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил.
Т.к. там строки, нужно было сделать так:

```
contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_LOGIN, "'" + loginEditText.getText().toString() + "'");
contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PASSWORD, "'" + passwordEditText.getText().toString() + "'");
contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_EMAIL, "'" + emailEditText.getText().toString() + "'");
```

Делал по примеру, но там такого не было, ну да не важно уже... Главное, что работает...

Comment: У Вас данные в базу будут записаны вместе с этими кавычками, а ошибка говорит, что в таблице уже есть запись с `email=admin@mail.ru`, и поскольку `email` объявлен как уникальный, вставка новой записи не выполнена.